# Create a New-PSDrive with username and a blank password

Tags: networking, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have disabled the blank password restriction in the group policy.

I'm unable to create a PS-Drive without the password with just code and no user inputs.

```
$user = "Admin"
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, (new-object System.Security.SecureString))
$root= "\\192.168.101.101\C$\Users\$user\Downloads"
New-PSDrive -Name Q -PSProvider filesystem -Root "$root" -Credential $creds
```

I get this error

```
New-PSDrive : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "$root" -Credential  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-PSDrive], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewDriveProviderException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

But if I comment out the Credentials Part

```
New-PSDrive -Name Q -PSProvider filesystem -Root "$root" #-Credential $creds
```

Then Dialog box appears to let me enter User and blank password.

Once I connect then next time onwards it lets me connect with dialog.

But I have many servers to connect to. How to directly connect without the dialog?

Appreciate any tips.